# Why app went crashed when multiple developers use the same port in Node JS

Tags: node.js, node-modules

We have a centralized server for development. We have installed "nodemon" for auto-refresh the server. Now multiple developers accessing the server from their local server using CLI. 
When Developer-1 runs the command "nodemon app.js", the server runs well. But after that when Developer-2 runs the same command he gets following error.

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::1111
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1277:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1325:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1412:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/john/sites/www/Tastii-Dev1-Portal/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/john/sites/www/Tastii-Dev1-Portal/app.js:41:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1304:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear to me.  Are you looking to fix the error and get your code working or are you asking a more general question along the line of “Why can’t two machines run simultaneously on the same port on my server”?

Comment: I think he didn’t read it or doesn’t understand what it means. Abhilash if you sspend some time reading them errors you receive you’ll find they are quite revealing.

Comment: It crash because... well someone already started the app...